# Change table layout with CSS

Tags: css, formatting, css-tables

I have a simple page that I need to look different for mobile devices and for desktops.  For desktops I need the logo for the side on the left side of several paragraphs.  For mobile, I need to remove the heading of the page and put the logo above the text.  So far I haven't had a lot of luck with this.  What should I do in order to get this to work with CSS?  At present, I just have the text and image laid out in a table with the logo in one column and the text in another.

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML or CSS, or at least a representative sample of it?  Off the top of my head, media queries might work well here.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a media query with a 'column' div instead of a table.

The CSS code could be as follows:

```
@media only screen and ( min-width: 1200px ) { 
  .two-col {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
       -moz-column-count: 2;
            column-count: 2;
      -webkit-column-gap: 1.5rem;
         -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
              column-gap: 1.5rem
  }
}
```

and then the HTML would be something like this:

```
<div class="two-col">
/* textual content here... */
</div>
```

You would need to tweak this to suit your situation, but basically it checks for mobile device or desktop with the media query. If it is a desktop it creates two columns of equal width. In your case the image would go first and then the text would wrap around to the right side column. If it is a mobile device it will not create the columns and it will show the image on top of the text.

Answer (score 0):

different values to css properties can be given by media queries.
you can see explanation on this matter [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

the common query for small devices is:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  ...
}
```

it queries all screen under 1034px and defines a new set of properties.